# How to handle Multiple SetInterval and ClearInterval in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using HTML table where each row's has one td field with Elapsed time Field (label) where it starts on demand means if i have 10 tr then it appears 10 elapsed time fields (labels).

I used following Code

```
var intval = '';
intval = setInterval("functionName ('tdID')", 1000);    
clearInterval(intval);
```

This resets all my fields.

How can i handle this for each td field(label)?

Comment: Put each `setInterval` reference in an array which matches the index of the related `tr`. Or alternatively, store it in a `data` attribute on the `tr`.

Comment: could you make fiddle for that question?

Answer (score -1):

for a single exectution you can you a timeout instead a interval
try this:

```
$('your-tr-selector').each(function() {
    var tr = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        //do your stuff here with the "tr" var
    }, 1000);
});
```